# Update module OpenERP with SSH putty

Tags: python, odoo, openerp-7, openerp-8

I have a problem when I want to update my module in OpenERP 7. I was try to update it from SSH putty, this is my script:

```
$ /opt/openerp/v7/server/openerp-server -c /etc/openerp-server.conf -d databasename -u all
```

and this is my openerp-server.conf :

```
admin_passwd = ***
db_host = ***
db_port = ***
db_user = openerp
db_password = False
addons_path = /opt/openerp/v7/addons, /opt/openerp/v7/web/addons, /opt/openerp/v7/server/openerp/addons
;log settings
logfile = /var/log/openerp/openerp-server.log
log_level = error
```

I get this error :

```
error: [errno 98] address already in use
```

there was an answer about post and I must use "kill" process, but after I did it, there nothing run in that process.

what should I do?

Comment: "echo manual | sudo tee /etc/init/your_app.override" rebot system starting without your_app. if want toenable it: "sudo rm -rf /etc/init/your_app.override" when rebooted your app starting on startup.

Comment: SDilmac: i don't get about your answer, can you give me more clearly explanation. pls..

Comment: of course : http://askubuntu.com/questions/19320/how-to-enable-or-disable-services

Answer (score 0):

Error says that OpenERP server is already in use. So first we need to kill that process and than we need to start it again.

Follow below steps.

Find openerp-server process id:-

- **ps -ax | grep openerp-server** this will give the process id and need to kill it for example 1234

Kill Process ID:-

- **sudo kill -9 1234**

Start Sever:-

- **sudo /etc/init.d/openerp-server start**

And update module from the GUI or if you want to upgrade all module from terminal than start openerp-server manually. Don't use script for it.

Comment: i did it. but when i run again 
$ /opt/openerp/v7/server/openerp-server -c /etc/openerp-server.conf -d databasename -u all

Comment: there was just like the process stopped, no activity for a long time. so i just cancel the proses. what this is about?